# Can't access to Object stored in multidimensional vector (C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, vector, gdb

I try to access to an object stored in a multidimensionnal vector :

It is an object of the class Case.

```
Carte::Carte(int x, int y) {
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
    for(int i; i<x; i++){
        carte.push_back(std::vector<Case*>());
        for(int j = 0; j<y; j++){
            Case aCase(i, j);
            carte[i].push_back(&aCase);
        }
    }
}
```

My Carte.h :

```
class Carte {
public:
Carte(int x, int y);
virtual ~Carte();
std::vector< std::vector<Case*> > carte;
int x,y;
};
```

Everything's fine but when I want to pass the object of Carte into the constructor on another class and try to read a variable of the class Case (Because there is objects of the class Case inside my vector) :

```
//I deleted the extra code...
Batiment::Batiment(Carte *carte) {
carte->carte[this->x][this->y]->libre = false;
}
```

This is my class Case :

```
class Case {
public:
Case(int x, int y);
virtual ~Case();
int x,y;
bool libre;
};
```

And when I execute, there is an "exit value = -1".

So I Debug, and it says :

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression "(((('std::_Vector_base<Case*,std::allocator<Case*> >' *) this))->_M_impl)"
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot access memory at address 0x78
```

There is no error during compilation but it seems I can't access to where the objects are in the vector...

Someone know why ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you storing pointers?

Comment: You mean ? 'std::vector< std::vector<Case*> >' ? Because I don't want that vector copy the object

Comment: @user3262670: So use `emplace_back`, or `push_back` a temporary (so that the copy can be elided). Or don't worry about the cost of copying a tiny object like this. Pointers are almost never the right way to avoid copying.

Comment: @user3262670: There's a cost-benefit ratio to consider, and you're on the wrong side of it. :)

Comment: Ok I will `push_back` without pointer because I don't have c++11 where I am supposed to compile, but the error is still here (Cannot access memory), why ? Thank you

Comment: my `main()` is still : `Batiment batiment(&carte);` I think there is another problem with `carte->carte[this->x][this->y]->libre = false;` which try to access to a variable in object, but can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You push a pointer to a local variable, a variable which will go out of scope and be destructed before you use that pointer, leading you to dereference a stray pointer and you will get [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The code in question:

```
for(int j = 0; j<y; j++){
    Case aCase(i, j);
    carte[i].push_back(&aCase);
}
```

The object `aCase` will go out of scope and be destructed in the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Oh thank you! So how may I do to create new objects which aren't locals ?

Comment: @user3262670 Simple, either create dynamically using `new`, or better yet stop using pointers at all and store actual objects.